# Pandas rolling average that takes missing points into account

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I would like to calculate a moving average on a dataframe that contains missing "points"

For the following example, we can see that the period of `09:00:02` has an average of `1.0`, where i would expect it to have the value of `0.5` because i would like to treat missing points (such as `09:00:01`) as zeroes.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import numpy as np

In [2]: df_time = pd.DataFrame({'B': [1, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]},
   ...:                        index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
   ...:                                 pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
   ...:                                 pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
   ...:                                 pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
   ...:                                 pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06')])
   ...:

In [3]: print(df_time)
   ...:
                       B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  2.0
2013-01-01 09:00:05  NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:06  4.0

In [4]: rolling = df_time.rolling('2s').mean()

In [5]: print(rolling)
                       B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  1.5
2013-01-01 09:00:05  NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:06  4.0
```

Is there an option to do that with pandas rolling?

Of course there is the option to fill the missing dates with reindex - but i am looking for a "native" rolling option, assuming it can also be more efficient

Comment: You can use df.fillna(0, inplace=True), this is extremely fast. Or you can use df.rolling.apply(lambda x : custom_mean(x)). But it will be slower no matter how you define the function custom_mean.

Comment: In the example, there aren't 'na' in the missing points, they just don't have rows
@LudoSchmidt

Comment: Ok, my bad I would resample on 1 s first before the rolling https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html